# Show that the wedge is antisymetric for 1-differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show that the wedge is antisymetric for 1-differential forms.

In other words, I want to show that $\alpha \wedge \beta = -\beta \wedge \alpha$, $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \Omega^0(U)$

Let

$\alpha = udx+vdy$ and $\beta = u'dx+v'dy$

If I calculate $\alpha \wedge \beta$, I get:

$$\alpha \wedge \beta = (udx+vdy) \wedge(u'dx+v'dy) = (uv'+vu')dxdy + uu'(dx)^2+vv'(dy)^2 = (uv'+vu')dxdy $$

Where as when I calculate $-\beta \wedge \alpha$ I get:

$$-\beta \wedge \alpha = (-u'dx-v'dy)\wedge (udx+vdy) = (-uv'-vu')dxdy$$

I obviously have  $\alpha \wedge \beta \neq -\beta \wedge \alpha$.

Comment: $dy\wedge dx \ne dx\wedge dy$

Comment: The forms $\alpha, \beta$ are in $\Omega^1(U)$, not $\Omega^0(U) = C^0(U)$.

Answer (score 4):

Your error here is the fact that
$$dx\wedge dy = -dy\wedge dx,$$
which you didn't use in your computations.